# Deserialize XML to List<string> failing with XmlArray, XmlElement, and XmlArrayItem

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I've got an object that is large, and contains several other objects.  The entire thing is deserialized from an XML file.

Everything in the deserialization is working correctly except for the following:

```
[XmlTypeAttribute("ClientInformation")]
public class ClientInfo
{
    public ClientInfo()
    {
        ClientName = "testclient";
        ClientDisplayFullName = "testclient";
        ClientDisplayShortName = "testclient";
        ContentClientName = "";
        ContentHeirarchy = new List<string>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The "ShortName" for this client (URL Friendly)
    /// </summary>
    public string ClientName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is used to determine what content path to use for content.
    /// normally the same as the ClientName.
    /// </summary>
    public string ContentClientName { get; set; }

    public List<string> ContentHierarchy { get; set; }

    public string ClientDisplayFullName { get; set; }

    public string ClientDisplayShortName { get; set; }

}
```

The problem resides with 'ContentHierarchy'.  The relevant section of the XML is as follows:

```
<ClientInformation>
    <ClientName>ABC</ClientName>
    <ContentClientName>ABC</ContentClientName>
    <ClientDisplayFullName>ABC&amp;D</ClientDisplayFullName>
    <ClientDisplayShortName>ABC&amp;D</ClientDisplayShortName>
    <ContentHierarchy>
        <Content>XYZB</Content>
        <Content>Base</Content>
    </ContentHierarchy>
</ClientInformation>
```

All of the non-list parts of this object deserialize correctly.

I'm trying to figure out what I need to use above the property declaration of ContentHierarchy to get the deserializer to populate it with the ContentHierarchy\Content items from the XML file.

I have tried using `XmlArray()`, `XmlArray(ContentHierarchy)`, `XmlElement(Content)`, `XmlElement(ContentHierarchy)`, `XmlArrayItem(Content)`, and various combinations of the above.

Each time, the `List<string>` has a Count of 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the attribute [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Content", IsNullable = false)] above the ContentHierarchy property. In the class constructor the property name is ContentHeirarchy, check if you property has the name ContentHeirarchy (wrong) or ContentHierarchy (right) too.

My full code:

```
    [XmlTypeAttribute("ClientInformation")]
public class ClientInfo
{
    public ClientInfo()
    {
        ClientName = "testclient";
        ClientDisplayFullName = "testclient";
        ClientDisplayShortName = "testclient";
        ContentClientName = "";
        ContentHierarchy = new List<string>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The "ShortName" for this client (URL Friendly)
    /// </summary>
    public string ClientName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is used to determine what content path to use for content.
    /// normally the same as the ClientName.
    /// </summary>
    public string ContentClientName { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Content", IsNullable = false)]
    public List<string> ContentHierarchy { get; set; }

    public string ClientDisplayFullName { get; set; }

    public string ClientDisplayShortName { get; set; }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml = "<ClientInformation>    <ClientName>ABC</ClientName>    <ContentClientName>ABC</ContentClientName>    <ClientDisplayFullName>ABC&amp;D</ClientDisplayFullName>    <ClientDisplayShortName>ABC&amp;D</ClientDisplayShortName>    <ContentHierarchy>        <Content>XYZB</Content>        <Content>Base</Content>    </ContentHierarchy></ClientInformation>";
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ClientInfo));
        var a = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(new MemoryStream(UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xml)));
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid creating a(nother) class - this is two or three objects down from the Root object in this XML, and the lines that access it are already long.  How can I change the XML so that the code that exists works?

Comment: Try to put the attribute [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Content", IsNullable = false)] above the ContentHierarchy property

Comment: I'll try it now, but I don't have high hopes as 'Content' isn't an Attribute, unless I have my terminology wrong.  EDIT: No, that did not work.  Still 0 results.

Comment: Strange, I´m testing and the list was filled. I´ll paste my full code above

Comment: So I did some further testing, and with the recommendation you gave me I added some entries to the list (programmatically) and Serialized the object...it gave me XML that's identical to what is failing to deserialize.

Comment: Did you try copy and paste my code above as a test? Could you send your c# code?

Comment: I am using the code above as a test - replacing my class with yours makes no change.  I can't bring in my C# code (beyond what's in the top post).  But as I said, when I Serialize my list using the class as you have set up there, it serializes just fine...

Comment: I have discovered the problem - another section of the code was eliminating the list (in a very subtle way, due to my not recalling that Lists are always passed by reference, not by copy) prior to hitting my code.  This lead to the list being populated (the referenced method works, as does declaring the list an [XmlArray] and specifying the [ArrayItem("Content")] and then eliminated before my debugger hit it.